# DocUSign: Is it possible to find out who sent an envelope by just using the envelopeId?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a marketing-site which does not have a database.

A user will come onto the site https://?envelopeId=123-456-789

I want to extract that DocUSign API from the params and then figure out who sent the envelope.

The below endpoint requires an accountId which I do not have. I am able to have the sender allow access for my app to do stuff on their behalf.

```
GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}
```

Answer (score 0):

> figure out who sent the envelope.

You can only do this if you have the account id, envelope id, and access permission.

If the sender or recipient logs in via your app then your app can retrieve the information about the envelope.

I think a recipient can use their own account id (instead of the sender's account id, but haven't checked this)